# Apache nifi: Difference between the flowfile State and StateManagement

Tags: apache-nifi

From what I've read here and there, the flowfile repository serves as a Write Ahead Log for apache Nifi.

When walking the configuration files, I've seen that there is a state-management configuration section. When in a Standalone mode, a local-provider is used and writes the state (by default) to .state/local/.

It seems like both the flowfile repo and the state are used both, for example, to recover from a system failure.

Would someone please explain what's the difference between them? Do they work together ?
Also, it's a best practice to have the flowfile repo and the content repo on two separate disks. What about the local state ? Should we avoid using the "boot" disk and offload to another one ? Which one: a dedicated ? Co-locate with another one (I'm co-locating database and flowfile repos).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The flow file repository keeps track of all the flow files in the system, which content they point to, which attributes they have, and where they are in the flow.

State Management is an API provided to processors/services that can be used to store and retrieve key/value pairs, typically for remembering where something left off. For example, a source processor that pulls data since some timestamp would want to store the last timestamp it used so that if NiFi restarts it can retrieve this value and start from there again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification. Is it a good practice to store this state outside of the root installation folder? Maybe alongside the database repo ?